# Constructor function with multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript

The constructor example I see a lot is

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
    this.nationality = "English";
}
```

But what if you want *many* parameters, like 20+. This seems like it would be inefficient. **What would be the correct and efficient way of declaring a constructor function that takes in many parameters?**

My end goal is to create an image slider with a lot of user settings (slidesToShow, slidesToScroll, slideClass, etc). So I am looking to have the user initialize it like and provide options. The way I have it now is kind of weird lol. example:

```
function Slider(options) {
 const slideClass = options.slideClass
}
```

and then it is initialized like so:

```
const demoSlider = new Slider({
 slideClass: 'image-slider'
})
```

But I am not using the *this* keyword like a normal constructor function and yet it is not a object literal either. So my code must just be built wrong? Just switched from mainly jQuery trying to learn/write vanilla JS the right way.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Having 20+ parameters is a sign of bad design.  If you really need to do that, you should make them named parameters (as you're doing now).

Comment: What's stopping you from doing `this.slideClass = options.slideClass`?

Comment: You can (should?) still use `this` with an options object: `this.slideClass = options.slideClass`. You can also set a default by using the short circuiting properties of the 'or' operator: `this.slideClass = options.slideClass || 'myClass'`

Comment: I was going to edit because I re-read it and was like hmm maybe THAT is the issue lol. But I'm not sure any other way to allow the user to set multiple options...

Comment: You could also copy all the properties at once like `Object.assign(this, options)`. But be aware that it is a shallow copy. Or you could just do `this.options = options`.

Comment: @FrankModica Mainly that I just trying to store the variable so that I can reuse it in my code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Maybe I misunderstood but isn't that what I have already done or no? I thought "options" was my settings object.

Comment: @FrankModica: "But be aware that it is a shallow copy."  That's true of `this.foo = options.foo` as well.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yep, I just find that people tend to assume that a copying function will do something more than assignment / reference copying. But you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Either just store an object under `this.options` :

```
 function Slider(options) {
    this.options = options;
 }
```

Or if you want it directly under `this`, just use Object assign:

```
 function Slider(options) {
   Object.assign(this, options);
    console.log(this.name);
 }

 new Slider({ name: "test" });
```

Comment: So really what I am doing now is fine? I guess the only difference is that I have put the options into variable names. Is that even necessary or should I just be using it like "options.slidesToShow" in my code instead of putting options.slidesToShow into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you better set them one by one, because they might have default value, ex:

```
this.height = (options.height)?options.height:100;
```

Also I think you're not quite understand the meaning of `new`.

You didn't use `this` which means all variables are in your function,

maybe in this case you only need to execute that function once to init your slider's event.

so you only need to call `Slider(options)` .

`new Slider()` will create a Object that can be reuse,

but you didn't even assign to a var like `var mySlider = new Slider()`...

You should consider in this case whether you need to design your **function** as a `function` or a `constructor`?